# How to wrap a Python executable to call another Python executable and use all of the argparse options?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, executable, argparse

I have the following Python executable called `fastq_preprocessor.py` in my path.  I'd like to create a wrapper called `fastq_preprocessor` that calls `fastq_preprocessor.py` which is in the same directory as `fastq_preprocessor`.  I want to be able to use all of the command line arguments natively with minimal code.  How can I configure `fastq_preprocessor` so it essentially calls `fastq_preprocessor.py` and utilizes all of the arguments in argparse?

My executable `fastq_preprocessor.py` has submodules.  Here is the entire script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Built-ins
import os, sys, argparse, importlib

# Version
__program__ = os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[-1]
__version__ = "2023.11.28"

# Accepted modules
accepted_programs = ["short", "long"]
script_directory  =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))

# Controller
def main(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="fastq_preprocessor",description="A fastq preprocessor for short and long read sequencing. Optional contamination removal.", add_help=True)
    parser.add_argument("program", choices=accepted_programs, help="`fastq_preprocessor` program for preprocessing. `short` for Illumina and `long` for ONT/PacBio.")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--citation", action='version', help="Show full citation (doi: 10.1186/s12859-022-04973-8)", version="Espinoza JL, Dupont CL.\nVEBA: a modular end-to-end suite for in silico recovery, clustering, and analysis of prokaryotic, microeukaryotic, and viral genomes from metagenomes.\nBMC Bioinformatics. 2022 Oct 12;23(1):419. doi: 10.1186/s12859-022-04973-8. PMID: 36224545.")
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--version", action='version', version="{} v{}".format(__program__, __version__))

    opts = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return opts.program


# Initialize
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Check version
    python_version = sys.version.split(" ")[0]
    condition_1 = int(python_version.split(".")[0]) == 3
    condition_2 = int(python_version.split(".")[1]) >= 6
    assert all([condition_1, condition_2]), "Python version must be >= 3.6.  You are running: {}\n{}".format(python_version, sys.executable)
    # Get the algorithm
    program = main([sys.argv[1]])
    module = importlib.import_module("fastq_preprocessor_{}".format(program))
    module.main(sys.argv[2:])
```

What is the minimal code to use wrap `fastq_preprocessor.py` in `fastq_preprocessor`?

I tried this which I got to kind of work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Built-ins
import os, sys, importlib

# Version
__program__ = os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[-1]
__version__ = "2023.11.28"

# Accepted modules
script_directory  =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))


if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    module = importlib.import_module("fastq_preprocessor")

    # Call the main function with the command line arguments
    module.main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I was able to do `./fastq_preprocessor -h`  but when I do `./fastq_preprocessor short -h`  or `./fastq_preprocessor long -h` it returns the same thing as `./fastq_preprocessor -h`.

Here's what I'm referring to when I say "it returns the same thing":

```
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:fastq_preprocessor jespinoz$ ./fastq_preprocessor -h
usage: fastq_preprocessor [-h] [-c] [-v] {short,long}

A fastq preprocessor for short and long read sequencing. Optional contamination removal.

positional arguments:
  {short,long}    `fastq_preprocessor` program for preprocessing. `short` for Illumina and `long` for ONT/PacBio.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -c, --citation  Show full citation (doi: 10.1186/s12859-022-04973-8)
  -v, --version   show program's version number and exit
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:fastq_preprocessor jespinoz$ ./fastq_preprocessor short -h
usage: fastq_preprocessor [-h] [-c] [-v] {short,long}

A fastq preprocessor for short and long read sequencing. Optional contamination removal.

positional arguments:
  {short,long}    `fastq_preprocessor` program for preprocessing. `short` for Illumina and `long` for ONT/PacBio.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -c, --citation  Show full citation (doi: 10.1186/s12859-022-04973-8)
  -v, --version   show program's version number and exit
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:fastq_preprocessor jespinoz$ ./fastq_preprocessor long -h
usage: fastq_preprocessor [-h] [-c] [-v] {short,long}

A fastq preprocessor for short and long read sequencing. Optional contamination removal.

positional arguments:
  {short,long}    `fastq_preprocessor` program for preprocessing. `short` for Illumina and `long` for ONT/PacBio.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -c, --citation  Show full citation (doi: 10.1186/s12859-022-04973-8)
  -v, --version   show program's version number and exit
```

Comment: Why are you unnecessarily slicing `argv` with `[1:]`? By slicing it, `short` and `long` effectively become `argv[0]` for `fastq_preprocessor.main` and are therefore ignored by `parse_args`.

Comment: For the `fastq_preprocessor`? If I don't then it is equivalent to fastq_preprocessor.py fastq_preprocessor -h

Comment: What do you mean by 'returns the same thing'? With '-h' you get the help, which will be the same regardless of other strings in `argv`.

Comment: @hpaul check out the edit I just made towards the end.

Comment: If you were using `subparsers` the help message would change depending whether you 'called' `short/long`.  But your `program` argument is a simple positional with choices. That doesn't alter the help message produced by the parser.

Comment: @hpaulj should I be using subparsers here instead?